# Adding child to parent in Jquery using variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically creating a div inside a div using Jquery. When I dump the child nodes for div1, it shows only text and strong. I was expecting 'div1' to have main_div_elem child and main_div_elem to have col_md_8_elem child.

Can someone help me to add col_md_8_elem to be child of main_div_elem  and main_div_elem as child of 'div1'?

### Output of console log from my JS function.

NodeList [ #text "Here",  ]

### Code:

```
var id = 1;
function tryThis() {
$( "#div1" ).append( "<strong>Hello</strong>" );
var main_div_elem = $('<div /', {id : 'main_div_elem'.concat(id), "class" : "row"});
var col_md_8_elem = $('<div /', {id : 'col_md_8_elem'.concat(id), "class" : "col-md-8"});
main_div_elem.append(col_md_8_elem);    
$('#div'.concat(id)).append(main_div_elem);
var children = document.getElementById("div1").childNodes;
console.log(children);
}
```

Trying to achieve following HTM code using jquery.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: Click `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Why `document.getElementById("div1").childNodes;` instead of `$("#div1").html()`

Answer (score 0):

Your `main_div_elem` and `col_md_8_elem` are not created correctly. The first parameters to the `$(..)` call are invalid HTML. You need to add a closing angle bracket (`>`) like this:

```js
var id = 1;

function tryThis() {
  $("#div1").append("<strong>Hello</strong>");
  var main_div_elem = $('<div />', {
    id: 'main_div_elem'.concat(id),
    "class": "row"
  });
  var col_md_8_elem = $('<div />', {
    id: 'col_md_8_elem'.concat(id),
    "class": "col-md-8"
  });
  main_div_elem.append(col_md_8_elem);
  $('#div'.concat(id)).append(main_div_elem);
  var children = $("#div1").html();
  console.log(children);
}
$(function() {
  tryThis();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: You may mark your question as resolved by clicking the check symbol next to my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hello  You can try the below code .I write it differently but hope it will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 1;
  var main_div_elem = "<div id=main_div_elem class='row'></div>"
  var main_div_elem8 = "<div id='col_md_8_elem' class='col-md-8'></div>"

  $("#div1").append(main_div_elem);
  $("#main_div_elem").append(main_div_elem8);

  var children = $("#div1").html();
  console.log(children);

});
```

```css
#div1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

#main_div_elem {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

#col_md_8_elem {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```